# я не могу понять из за чего возникла ошибка builtin_function_or_method object is not subscripted когда я пытаюсь запустить код?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

я сделал калькулятор в котором все переменные состоят из int(input()), и на самую главную из них в которой хранится все математические символы которые знает программа, при запуске выдает ошибку builtin_function_or_method object is not subscripted. я видел как решить похожую ошибку в разных языках но не нашел как решить ее в python. я пробовал переназывать переменную или двигать условие связанное с ней поближе к этой переменной, но ничего не помогает

```py
count = input['Write type of operation'] #потрібно написати тип операції 
num1 = int(input("Write number")) #перша цифра для операції 
num2 = int(input("Write second number")) #друга цифра для операції 
if count == "division": 
    print(num1/num2) 
else: 
    if count == 'addition': 
        print(num1 + num2) 
    if count == 'subtraction': 
        print(num1 - num2) 
    else: 
        print('incorrect operation')
```

Comment: может, мы не будем гадать, а в просто код покажите?

Comment: count= input['Write type of operation']
#потрібно написати тип операції
num1= int(input("Write number"))
#перша цифра для операції
num2= int(input("Write second number"))
#друга цифра для операції
if count== "division":
    print(num1/num2)
else:
    if count== 'addition':
        print(num1 + num2)
if count== 'subtraction':
    print(num1 - num2)
else:
    print('incorrect operation')

Comment: на переменную count жаловался VS Cde

Comment: вы код перенесите в вопрос - здесь невозможно его читать

Comment: Добавьте код из комментария в вопрос нажав "править", перед и после кода поставьте тройный апострофы, для вставки кода с форматированием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы написали функцию `input` c квадратными скобками (`[]`), а не с круглыми (`()`)

```py
count = input('Write type of operation') #  Вот тут была ошибка
num1 = int(input("Write number"))
num2 = int(input("Write second number"))
if count == "division": 
    print(num1/num2) 
else: 
    if count == 'addition': 
        print(num1 + num2) 
    if count == 'subtraction': 
        print(num1 - num2) 
    else: 
        print('incorrect operation')
```